# How would I merge these arrays together?

Tags: php

I am having a lot of trouble merging these arrays together, I have tried array_merge and array_merge_recursive but they aren't giving me the results that I want. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be amazing, I've been banging my head against the table for hours now...

Array 1:

```
array [
  0 => array [
    "start" => "04/26/2015 8:00 AM"
  ]
  1 => array [
    "start" => "04/26/2015 9:00 AM"
  ]
]
```

Array 2:

```
array [
  0 => array [
    "end" => "04/26/2015 10:00 AM"
  ]
  1 => array [
    "end" => "04/26/2015 11:00 AM"
  ]
]
```

Array 3:

```
array:2 [
  0 => "1"
  1 => "3"
]
```

And the result that I want, don't worry about the "2015-04-26" that is irrelevant to this question:

```
array [
  "2015-04-26" => array [
    "cities" => array [
      1 => array [
        "start" => "04/26/2015 8:00 AM"
        "end" => "04/26/2015 10:00 AM"
      ]
      3 => array [
        "start" => "04/26/2015 9:00 AM"
        "end" => "04/26/2015 11:00 AM"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: What does `array:3` mean in the result?

Comment: Oh that's irrelevant, that's how my php debugger outputs arrays. I'll remove those.

Comment: It looks like it should be the size of the array, except that those arrays only have 2 elements, not 3.

Comment: Yeah it is, it has nothing to do with the question so please disregard!

Comment: What did you try until now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case the following code will do the trick. But you should reconsider your data structure.

```
$arrStart = [
    0 => [
        "start" => "04/26/2015 8:00 AM",
    ],
    1 => [
        "start" => "04/26/2015 9:00 AM",
    ],
];

$arrEnd = [
    0 => [
        "end" => "04/26/2015 10:00 AM",
    ],
    1 => [
        "end" => "04/26/2015 11:00 AM",
    ],
];

$keys = [
  0 => "1",
  1 => "3",
];

$result = [];

foreach ($keys as $i => $key) {
    $result[$key] = [
        'start' => $arrStart[$i]['start'],
        'end'   => $arrEnd[$i]['end'],
    ];    
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: You both helped me out tremendously, saved me hours... Seriously thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

It's just a simple `for` loop that gets the values from each input array and combines them into the output array.

```
$result = array('2015-04-26' > array('cities' => array()));
foreach ($array1 as $id => $val1) {
    $start = $val1['start'];
    $end = $array2[$id]['end'];
    $key = $array3[$id];
    $result['2015-04-26']['cities'][$key] = array('start' => $start, 'end' => $end);
}
```